# I need to increase sheet number in formula when copying

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently trying to pull some data together from about 78/79 sheets (they are named Security officer 1, security officer 2 etc etc)

I am using this formula to pull the names onto my main sheet:

```
='Security Officer 1'!$E$3
```

How can I change the formula so when I copy down, it automatically changes the sheet name from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on an so forth? I believe it has something to do with the indirect function?

Thanks In advance

Comment: Why don't you trick it? Separate the formula in text strings in cells, grow the number, then `concatenate` them?
For example A1: `='Security Officer ` B1:`1` C1: `'!$E$3`, afterwards use `concatenate(a1,b1,c1)` for each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDIRECT` & `ROWS` for this:

```
=INDIRECT("'Security Officer "&ROWS($E$4:E4)&"'!E3")
```

the above will give you Cell `E3` from tab `Security Officer 1`

And when you drag it down, it will go to `Security Officer 2`

Comment: where has the E4 come from??? Sorry. Not an advanced excel user!! thanks for your help

Comment: So `ROWS($E$4:E4)` will count how many rows between `E4` and `E4`, which is 1, the 1 goes on the end of security officer, then when dragged down it becomes `ROWS($E$4:E5)` and gives you a 2, for security officer 2,

Comment: @PeterH, maybe `ROWS($E$3:E3)` would be less confusing.

Comment: @ReyJuna yeah maybe, `ROWS` is only used to generate a number that will increment when dragged down